# Subclipse - How to mark a major revision?

Tags: eclipse, version-control, subclipse

How does one go about marking a major revision using the Subclipse plugin? I'd like to mark a project at the end of an iteration such that it's possible to revert if necessary without going through endless changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your repository is divided into branches, trunk and tags, i'd suggest that you create a new tag.

Use the "Branch/Tag" command after commiting your work. It makes a copy that is called a tag and is stored (usually) in the "tags" folder.

Comment: Thanks. Had trouble finding out how to create a tag. The following should be useful: http://ist.berkeley.edu/as-ag/tools/usage/subclipse-usage-tips.html

Comment: If this answer helped you it'll be much appreciated if you could "check" this answer =)

Comment: It did indeed help. Done :)